# How to Convert from SQL Datetime UTC to the LocalDateTime and Back Again

Tags: java, mysql

The code is supposed to take the date and time from the database, label it as UTC(or maybe it should already know it's UTC?), convert it to the local time zone and then return the date and time as a timestamp.

Currently the code only prints out the date/time that is in the database and saves the local time to the database.

Am I interpreting my code wrong? Am I missing a step to convert the times?

Thank you for any additional assistance

```java
package Utils;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;


public class DateTimeConverter {

    public static Timestamp toLocalDateTime(Timestamp utc){
        //identify as UTC
        ZonedDateTime utcZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(utc.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        Instant timestamp = utcZonedDateTime.toInstant();
        //set the timestamp to the systems default zone
        ZonedDateTime utcToLocal = timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        System.out.println(Timestamp.from(utcToLocal.toInstant()));

        return Timestamp.from(utcToLocal.toInstant());
    }

    public static Timestamp toUTC(Timestamp ldt){
        //identify as systems default zoneid
        ZonedDateTime localZDT = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(ldt.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        Instant timestamp = localZDT.toInstant();
        //set the timestamp to UTC zoneid
        ZonedDateTime localToUTC = timestamp.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        System.out.println(Timestamp.from(localToUTC.toInstant()));

        return Timestamp.from(localToUTC.toInstant());

    }

}
```

Comment: show how do you call these methods. What are the exact values and what should be expected?

Comment: Thank you. How much context is needed? I mainly put a `Timestamp` in and get a `Timestamp` out. i.e.: `Timestamp start = DateTimeConverter.toUTC(appointment.getStartTime());` where `appointment.getStartTime()` is a `Timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
    public static Timestamp toLocalDateTime(Timestamp utc){

        LocalDateTime ldt = utc.toLocalDateTime();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        ZonedDateTime newZdt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        LocalDateTime newLdt = newZdt.toLocalDateTime();

        return Timestamp.valueOf(newLdt);

    }

    public static Timestamp toUTC(Timestamp ts){

        LocalDateTime ldt = ts.toLocalDateTime();
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        ZonedDateTime newZdt = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        LocalDateTime newLdt = newZdt.toLocalDateTime();

        return Timestamp.valueOf(newLdt);

    }
```